# Shutdown Debian from php script

Tags: debian, php, shutdown, sudo, sudoers

I am trying to shutdown my RaspberryPi running Raspbian from a php script running on lighttpd webserver.
`shell_exec("sudo /sbin/shutdown -h now 2>&1");`

I added `lighttpd ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /sbin/shutdown` to my /etc/sudoers file and checked that `Defaults !requiretty` is set.

I still get "sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified" when running the script.

Can somebody please help me? Thanks!

Comment: I think you may want the `shell_exec` function instead of `exec` since that is a shell command (I think that's how it works).  I am not 100% sure (hence the comment), but may be worth a try.

Comment: Output redirection (`2>&1`) requires a shell; try removing that from the command and see if you get a different result.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Actually I already tried shell_exec in the first place. I just have copied the wrong command to my question. And exec("sudo /sbin/shutdown -h now"); doesn't work either.

Comment: Are you sure that lighttpd is running as user lighttpd?
In a php script, `echo \`whoami\``;
It might be www-data or http instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lighttpd might not be running as user `lighttpd`.

In a PHP script, write the following to find out what user it runs with:

```
echo shell_exec('whoami');
```

It might be `www-data` or `http` instead.

Comment: Thank you ElanMan for your hint. The correct user was indeed www-data and not lighttpd as I have read somwehere else. Now it works as expected.